# Combined resolvers always throw "cannot read property 'apply' of undefined" error

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I am trying to attach the following guard:

```
export const isSupplier=(_,__,{me})=>{
    
  me.role==="supplier" ? skip : new ForbiddenError('Not authenticated as supplier.');
}
```

To a resolver, like this:

```
addProductNow:combineResolvers(
            isSupplier,
            async (_,{name,price,description,url,stock},{dataSources,me})=>{

            const supplierId=me.id
            console.log(supplierId)
            const supplier=await dataSources.SupplierAPI.findSupplierById(supplierId)
            
            const newProduct=await dataSources.ProductAPI.addProduct(name,price,description,url,stock,supplierId,{ttlInSeconds:60*20})
            return newProduct
        }),
```

Yet it always returns the error "cannot read property 'apply' of undefined". I have tried to log something in the guard , yet it seems like it never gets executed. After removing the guard from the resolver everything works fine and logging 'me' shows the expected value. Am I doing something wrong ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're using for your "guards", but I assume it's because you're not doing or returning anything in this function, and it's expecting a function (what it calls "apply" on):

```js
export const isSupplier=(_,__,{me})=>{
    
  me.role==="supplier" ? skip : new ForbiddenError('Not authenticated as supplier.');
}
```

Did you mean to do this:

```js
export const isSupplier=(_,__,{me})=>{
    
  return me.role==="supplier" ? skip : new ForbiddenError('Not authenticated as supplier.');
}
```

---

Follow-up Edit:

From googling some of your variable names, I assume you're using `graphql-resolvers`.

In the example they provide, they use "arrow functions with implicit return", which is when you

1. Don't add Braces around the body of your function
2. Put the whole thing in one expression

The result of the function becomes whatever the expression after the arrow results in:

```js
const isAuthenticated = (root, args, { user }) => user ? skip : new Error('Not authenticated')
```

This can be converted to using "explicit returns" by adding braces and the `return` keyword like this:

```js
const isAuthenticated = (root, args, { user }) => {
  return user ? skip : new Error('Not authenticated')
}
```

Your code as documented, however, added the braces but NOT the `return` and therefore always returns `undefined`. Looking at [the source code of that library](https://github.com/lucasconstantino/graphql-resolvers/blob/master/src/combineResolvers.js#L12), if you don't return EXACTLY `skip` it resolves to whatever the return value of your function was (in this case `undefined`).

Can you share more information about your stack trace to show WHAT is trying to call .apply on what?

Comment: Same error of "cannot read property apply of undefined". Also, I'm not sure its needed to use return with something like skip and new ForbiddenError , or any error for that matter. What do you say ?

Comment: You absolutely need `return`. I've updated my comment to provide more information and hopefully get you to the next step.

Comment: Thanks so much ! Indeed I need a return based on wether on not curly braces are used, yet , after refactoring it , it still throws the  "cannot read property apply of undefined" when the mutation is triggered.

Comment: Can you share more information in your about your stack trace to show WHAT is trying to call .apply on what and where in the code? Based off what you've shared, I don't think I can get you further.